# Predictive text leads to auto completion in WebView

Tags: android, webview, autocomplete

I have a WebView with a form. Let's say my name is Richard Thompson and I have a contact named Richard McEntire. Whenever I type Richard in a text box the predictive text bar tells me that I have a contact with that name. When I tap space to start typing my last name the field auto completes to Richard McEntire.
I've tried:

```
mWebView.clearFormData();
mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

and, in the text box:

```
autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"
```

But it's not working.
If that cannot be fixed, can I get rid of the predictive text bar?

Comment: Please add enough code and the layout so that it's possible to understand what your code does.

Comment: I don't think they let me. I have 573 lines in the MainActivity without counting the layout...